# How do you add comments to MySQL queries, so they show in logs?

Tags: mysql, comments

I want to be able to add a little note, at the beginning of each query, so when I see it in the processlist, or "mytop", I can tell where it’s running.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure this would work, but it is worth trying.

Simply add `"/* some comment or tag */ "` before whatever SQL query is sent normally.

It is possible that MySQL server will remove this comment as part of its query analysis/preparation, but it may just leave it as well, so it shows as such in logs and other monitoring tools.

In case the comments get stripped away, and assuming SELECT queries, a slight variation on the above would be to add a calculated column as the first thing after SELECT, something like

```
SELECT IF('some comment/tag' = '', 1, 0) AS BogusMarker, here-start-the-original-select-list
-- or
SELECT 'some [short] comment/tag' AS QueryID, here-start-the-original-select-list
```

This approach has the drawback of introducing an extra column value, with each of the results row.  The latter form, actually uses the "comment/tag" value as this value, which may be helpful for debugging purposes.

Comment: You could do something like `SELECT IF('owner' = 'joe', 'additional comment', original_first_column)` to avoid the extra column.

Comment: FWIW MySQL server does not strip comments out, but the `mysql` command-line client does.

Answer (score 4):

I discovered this today:

MySQL supports the strange syntax:

```
/*!<min-version> code here */
```

to embed code that will only be interpreted by MySQL, and only MySQL of a specified minimum version.

This is documented at *[9.7 Comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html)* (used by mysqldump, for example).

Such comments will not be parsed out, and included in the processlist, unlike normal ones, and that even if the code is not actually executed.

So you can do something like

```
/*!999999 comment goes here */ select foo from bla;
```

to have a comment that will show up in the processlist, but not alter the code. (Until MySQL developers decide to bloat their release numbering and release a version numbered over 99.99.99, in which case you will just have to add another digit.)